# Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4.2 and SQL Server 2016 Express with all SP's installed, Crystal Reports Developer with SP25 installed.

I have a few reports in the solution and have published the program to include SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .Net Framework as a prerequisite. The programming is in C# WPF. The developer computers user win 10 and 7

**PROBLEM**: I am able to access the reports within Visual Studio and after publishing on the development computers, I can access the reports and the program functions normally. However, when I install the published version on the users computer, accessing any report or program with a print option (e.g. enter and printing an invoice) causes the program to close. Accessing any other option without a print option display normally. The users are on Windows 10.

Since this happens only when accessing Crystal Reports, I am not sure if I am missing a Crystal Reports component.

Any assistance will be most appreciated and I thank you in advance

Bhuven

Comment: Have you attempted using a Try Catch block in your C# too see if there is an error prior to the program closing?  Also, how are you printing the reports?  Are you launching the Report Viewer, then clicking the print button within the viewer, or are you using C# to send a print command to the CR runtime component?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I resolved the problem - I did not install the crystal reports runtime on the users terminals,